# NFC Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, nfc

I'm trying to use the NFC Plugin but i have an error "Signature could not verify". I write the code generating the signature of the data and a selfsigned certificate. But when I put all them together i shows me that error. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The Signature Record support is experimental at this point, so I advise you to check out the sources for a deeper investigation.